# Why do I encounter DirectoryNotEmptyException while deleting a directory recursively?

Tags: java, io, java-7, nio

I have some code, which ought to delete a directory recursively, using the java.nio package. The code was basically copied from http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_7_deleting_recursively_a, and looks like follows:

```
public class NotEmptyDirDemo {
    public static void main(String[] pArgs) throws Exception {
        final Path path = Paths.get("d:/tmp/woda");
        Assert.assertTrue(Files.isDirectory(path));
        new NotEmptyDirDemo().removeDir(path);
        Assert.assertFalse(Files.isDirectory(path));
    }

    protected void removeDir(Path pDir) throws IOException {
        final FileVisitor<Path> fv = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path pDir,
                             BasicFileAttributes pAttrs) throws IOException {
                return super.preVisitDirectory(pDir, pAttrs);
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path pDir, IOException pExc) throws IOException {
                final FileVisitResult res = super.postVisitDirectory(pDir, pExc);
                Files.delete(pDir);
                return res;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path pFile, BasicFileAttributes pAttrs) throws IOException {
                if (!Files.isWritable(pFile)) {
                    pFile.toFile().setWritable(true);
                }
                Files.delete(pFile);
                return super.visitFile(pFile, pAttrs);
            }
        };
        Files.walkFileTree(pDir, fv);
    }
}
```

Now, I can imagine all bad things to happen when executing that stuff (For example, missing permissions for delete, and the like. Howver, this one surprises me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException:
     d:\tmp\woda\woda\work
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:266)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
at com.foo.demo.NotEmptyDirDemo$1.postVisitDirectory(NotEmptyDirDemo.java:32)
at com.foo.demo.NotEmptyDirDemo$1.postVisitDirectory(NotEmptyDirDemo.java:1)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2688)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
at com.foo.demo.NotEmptyDirDemo.removeDir(NotEmptyDirDemo.java:45)
at com.foo.demo.NotEmptyDirDemo.main(NotEmptyDirDemo.java:18)
```

The directory walker iterates over the directory tree. If it finds a directory, it iterates over that, and finally deletes it (in postVisitDirectory). If it finds a file, that is deleted too (in visitFile).

So, a directory, which is being deleted, should always be empty. However, it isn't.

Any reasonable explanation?

Thanks,

Jochen

Comment: Just speculating, but I think it's quite possible there's a file that for some reason is not deletable, but Files.delete isn't throwing an Exception, so the file is still there when you are trying to delete the directory

Comment: FileVisitor defines four methods.  Trying implementing the fourth method and placing a print statement in it;  it may reveal which files, if any, could not be visited.